# Kendo UI MVVM - How to get the opposite or NOT or ! of a binary variable when data-binding

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

What I want to do is this:

```
<input data-bind="value: Adult.FirstName, visible: editable" />
<span data-bind="text: Adult.FirstName, visible: !editable"></span>

viewModel = kendo.observable({
    editable: false
});
```

But I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !
```

The only ways I’ve been able to figure out how to do it are:

```
<input data-bind="value: Adult.FirstName, visible: editable" />
<span data-bind="text: Adult.FirstName, visible: not('editable')"></span>

viewModel = kendo.observable({
    editable: false,
    not: function(value) { return !this.get(value);},
});
```

and:

```
<input data-bind="value: Adult.FirstName, visible: editable" />
<span data-bind="text: Adult.FirstName, visible: notEditable"></span>

viewModel = kendo.observable({
    editable: false,
    notEditable: function() { return !this.get("editable");},
});
```

But I would rather just keep track of the one variable with no extra functions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just use the invisible data bind.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/invisible

Or you can monitor the change event of your viewModel, check for editable changing, and change a second viewModel property to the opposite value.  Then you'd have two properties, but really only have to manage one of them.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've looked at that page in their documentation about MVVM and didn't see the bindings folder or click on it.  What a wealth of information in that folder!  Several other questions I've left unanswered were just answered.  Thank you!

Comment: The invisible trait will solve this particular use case.  Thank you.  So I guess the broader question of being able to do a !someVariable is just not allowed in kendo MVVM due to separation of concerns.

Comment: i have the same issue i need the css bind if NOT, and i would love to be able to just add !